# unmarshall anonymous json field to "named" field

Tags: go

Say I have the following json

```
{
    "unknown": {
        "knownArray": [
            {"property": "somevalue", "otherproperty": false}
        ],
        "otherKnownArray": [""]
    }
}
```

And I have the following structs to represent this data

```
type Model struct {
    ObjectName string
    KnownArray []KnownType `json:"knownArray"`
    OtherKnownArray []string `json:"otherKnownArray"`
}

type KnownType struct {
    Property string `json:"property1"`
    Otherproperty bool   `json:"otherproperty"`
}
```

doing

```
var model Model

json.Unmarshal(content, &model)
```

Does not deserialize any of the json unfortunately.

**How do I deserialize to my Model correctly?**
**How do I deserialize the json so that ObjectName = "unknown"?**

Im not quite understanding the internals of encoding/json when it comes to anonymous json fields.

Ive also tried wrapping Model in a third "outer" Model, but still does not work with the anonymous json field.

Comment: Use `map[string]*Model`, then range over the map and use the key to set the ObjectName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can use map[string]Model to encode. https://play.golang.org/p/QWXQZFjBgRB

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Model struct {
    ObjectName string
    KnownArray []KnownType `json:"knownArray"`
    OtherKnownArray []string `json:"otherKnownArray"`
}

type KnownType struct {
    Property string `json:"property"`
    Otherproperty bool   `json:"otherproperty"`
}

func main() {
        jsonstring := `{
            "unknown": {
                "knownArray": [
                        {"property": "somevalue", "otherproperty": false}
                ],
                "otherKnownArray": [""]
            }
    }`
    a := make(map[string]Model)
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonstring), &a)
    var m Model
    for k, v := range(a) {
        m = v
        m.ObjectName = k
        break
    }
    fmt.Println(m.ObjectName, m.KnownArray, m.OtherKnownArray)
}
```

Comment: This answers half the question, which is awesome! im am 100% further now. But what about the property "ObjectName"? or do I just assign it after the fact?

Comment: @VisualBean, I updated the answer. Yes, you just assign it